# When trying to view table view after viewing another, app crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

i have a tough one for you today. I have two tableViews in my app the first is on the first page. There are two other pages the user drills down to get to the second table view. After i leave the first table view, i can press the back buttons to get back perfectly until i reach the second table view. As soon as i drill down to the second table view and then try to return to the first via pressing the back buttons. As soon as i get to the last back button to return to the first table view, the app crashes. The code for the back buttons is simply:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Any Help Would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks everyone!! :D

Comment: You need to post a lot more code because there is nothing wrong with that method; there is probably a random problem somewhere that you are overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I create a modal view controller from a XIB, the automatic @property generator duplicates things in the Dealloc method, thus throwing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the view is dismissed.  Make sure you aren't releasing something twice.

Comment: Perfect!!:D i was releasing my table view iboutlet! Thanks a bunch! :D

Comment: Your answer sort of reads as if one shouldn't send `release` in `dealloc`, which isn't true, since `dealloc` is the final place to do memory cleanup (and might run without, e.g., `viewDidUnload` having been). An outlet should be set to `nil` if it is released outside of `dealloc` so that `release` can safely be sent.

Comment: Josh, my answer means that when I create a local variable and an @property through the XIB, then it DUPLICATES the releases in Dealloc

Comment: You mean you already have `[dinkus release];` in `dealloc` and Xcode inserts _another_ `[dinkus release]`? That sounds like it's worth [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn).

Comment: No, I understand why it does it.  Xcode expects your ivars and local vars to be named differently (i.e. _object = object), so when properties are named the same as locals it releases them in dealloc twice.  No bug, just Xcode expecting a different input

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your are releasing something too early. Open you app in instruments (command + i) and run a zombie test.

As soon as you see zombie has been messaged expand the right panel and have a look at the user code (your code) blocks. Indicated by the back person icon.

Double click that and it will indicate what it was trying to access that had already been released.

Answer (score 1):

Are your tableviews being displayed in a modal window? If not, why are you calling **[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]**? Shouldn't you be calling **[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES]**?

If you're using a UINavigationController, the back button functionality should be provided automatically.

Comment: IM pretty new to this, so may i ask what exactly is a modal window?? thanks for the help! :D. also, im not using a nav controller. So i added the back functionality myself!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES] to

then for back you write  as mentioned below:

- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
  // Tell the controller to go back
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }

if you are using [self presentmodalviewcontroller:  animated:]
then only [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] will work

Comment: i already have `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, but thanks for the help!:D

Answer (score 0):

you try this  [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES]